# Counting the number of recursions

Tags: haskell

I have some code that approximates a solution recusively, what it actually does is not important, but it works towards r' == rt by varying mg (m guess, starting with 4.0 because I "know" that ought to be in the ballpark).

```
solve_m f ar st qt = solve_m' f ar st qt 4.0
  where
    solve_m' f ar st qt mg 
      | rd > precis    = f' (mg - sf)  
      | rd < (-precis) = f' (mg + sf)  
      | otherwise = mg
        where 
          f' = solve_m' f ar st qt
          rt = st + qt   
          r' = f st ar mg 
          rd = rt - r'    
          sf = abs(rd)
```

What I would like to be able to do is count the number of cycles, I know the right way to do this is with the State monad, but what is the most elegant way to fit the put/get into a function like this? Make f' a do block? Or is it simply to add a counter solve_m' and return (counter, mg)?

Thanks!

Edit: This seems to be basically what I want, and no Monads necessary:

```
solve_m f ar st qt = (last (series), length(series))
  where
  series = takeWhile termPred (iterate solve_m' 4.0)
  termPred m' = (abs (rt - (f st ar m'))) > precis
  rt = st + qt   
  solve_m' mg 
    | rt > r' = (mg - sf)  
    | rt < r' = (mg + sf)  
      where
        r' = f st ar mg 
        rd = rt - r' 
        sf = abs(rd)
```

Still looks a little messy (repeated code) but I'll tidy it up... This is getting me acceptable results in 1/10000th of the iterations of the code it will replace!

Comment: If you just want to see how much recursion is there for some test input, you could profile it (tells you how often the function is called). See http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/profiling.html

Comment: "I know the right way to do this is with the State monad"  How do you know that?  `State` is just syntactic sugar for passing/returning an extra value.  Like any sugar there will be cases where the unsugared form is nicer.

Comment: Incidentally, all the parameters that are passed to f produce a lot of syntactic noise.  Abstracting out the function that estimates the error in mg (`err mg = rt - f st ar mg`), your step function is `\mg -> mg - err mg`, and your acceptance criterion is `abs (err mg) <= precis`, assuming precis is positive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without looking at your algorithm, the generic way to do this is divide up your termination criteria from the iterative algorithm:

```
terminationPred :: a -> Bool
algorithm :: a -> a
```

then use either iterate and takeWhile:

```
itermediates = takeWhile (not . terminationPred) . iterate algorithm
resultAndRecursions :: a -> (a, Int)
resultAndRecursions a = (last (intermediates a), length (intermediates a) - 1)
-- you'd want to make your own safe function here, not use last and length
```

or unfold:

```
intermediates = unfoldr op
  where
  op a | terminationPred a = Nothing
       | otherwise = let a' = algorithm a
                     in Just (a', a')
```

EDIT: also notice these two intermediates are slightly different in that the first maintains the base case (the input `a`, hence the `- 1`) while the second does not and thus would have a minor difference in the complementary `resultAndRecursions`.

Comment: Oh, and... +1, thanks for stepping up and giving a proper answer after I managed to confuse myself. :\ Haven't had enough coffee today I guess.

Comment: I'm a bit new to haskell... What's the `algorithm a in Just...` syntax? I haven't run into it yet? A link to the docs would be awesome

Comment: @Daenyth: The full expression is the form `let x = foo in bar ...`. It's a local declaration, scoped over the expression following `in`. It's kinda like doing `(\x -> bar ...) foo`.

Comment: @Daeyth: I reformatted it to expose the association of `let` and `in`.  In something approximating C syntax this would be `new_a = algorithm a ; return (Just (new_a,new_a));`.  See [this tutorial](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#let-it-be).

Comment: @camccann, @TomMD: Oh duh, how did I not notice that. I guess I tripped up on the `algorithm` function that I didn't recognize.

Comment: Rather than using a `let`, you could also define `a'` as one of the `where` clauses (thanks to laziness, it will be evaluated — or not — at the same time anyway).

Comment: @Chuck right, but it would have to be a sub-where clause of `op`, not in the higher-level `where` under `intermediates` seeing as `a` isn't bound there.

Answer (score 4):

Well, first of all, you can remove most of the arguments to `solve_m'`: they don't change in recursive calls, and the arguments of `solve_m` are in scope for the `where` clause. This also makes the `f'` function unnecessary.

```
solve_m f ar st qt = solve_m' 4.0
  where
    solve_m' mg 
      | rd > precis    = solve_m' (mg - sf)  
      | rd < (-precis) = solve_m' (mg + sf)  
      | otherwise = mg
        where 
          rt = st + qt   
          r' = f st ar mg 
          rd = rt - r'    
          sf = abs(rd)
```

Now, `solve_m'` has type `Double -> Double`, because all it does is perform the next iteration and then either finish or call itself tail-recursively. As it happens, the standard libraries include a function called `iterate` with type `(a -> a) -> a -> [a]`, which takes such a function and <strike>produces an (possibly infinite) list of each step in the iteration. The number of recursive calls needed is, of course, precisely the length of the resulting list.</strike> produces an embarrassing mistake in my answer.

What `iterate` actually does is produce an infinite list, in this case with endlessly repeating copies of the "final" result. Not really what you want. I was probably thinking of `unfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]`.

The other option--which I actually prefer--would be to remove the guard that checks for the answer being close enough and use `iterate` after all, producing an infinite list of new approximations, then consume the resulting list comparing adjacent elements to see how close you're getting. I'd give some example code but given the earlier mistake that might be unwise.

**EDIT:** Okay, for the sake of completeness, here's a couple quick examples:

Using `iterate` and `takeWhile`:

```
solve_m_iter f ar st qt = takeWhile notDoneYet $ iterate nextApprox 4.0
  where rd mg = st + qt - f st ar mg
        notDoneYet mg = abs (rd mg) > precis
        nextApprox  mg | rd mg > precis  = mg - abs (rd mg)
                       | rd mg < -precis = mg + abs (rd mg)
```

Using `unfoldr`:

```
solve_m_unfold f ar st qt = unfoldr nextApprox
  where nextApprox mg | rd > precis  = keep $ mg - abs rd
                      | rd < -precis = keep $ mg + abs rd
                      | otherwise    = Nothing
            where rd = st + qt - f st ar mg
                  keep x = Just (x, x)
```

And a slightly better function to get the result without traversing the list twice:

```
getResult = foldl (\(n, _) x -> (n + 1, x)) (0, 4.0)
```

Definitely quick-and-dirty code, but hopefully helpful.

Comment: Nitpick: `iterate` always produces an infinite list.  You have to use `take`, `takeWhile`, or something similar to get a finite list out of it.

Comment: Since when will `iterate` produce anything besides an infinite list?  I think you're thinking of `unfold` or some sort of `takeWhile pred . iterate f`?

Comment: @Antal S-Z: Wow, you're right, and that's not really a nitpick. Shows what I get for typing faster than I'm thinking. Probably got my wires crossed between iterate and unfold, as @TomMD guessed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on scope, that's much cleaner. I don't understand tho' the use of iterate here - surely it always tries to create an infinite list (and in this case, once the solution is reached it will simply repeat it forever). Coding it as: solve_m f ar st qt = (last (series), length(series))
  where
  series = iterate solve_m' 4.0 goes on forever...

Comment: @Gaius: Yes, I bungled that part badly, my apologies. Either extract the termination predicate and use `takeWhile` or replace `iterate` with `unfoldr` and use `Nothing` to indicate completion, as @TomMD explained.

Comment: @camccann: I need the guard to know which way to adjust mg - do you mean drop the otherwise? Thanks :-)

Comment: @Gaius: Glad to hear it--I added a couple quick examples anyway, and sorry again for the confusion earlier.